# What is the difference between .. and _ in Rust?

Tags: rust, pattern-matching, match

What is the difference between two periods and underscore in this case:

```
 let a = Some("a");
    match a {
        Some(_) => println!("we are in match _"),

        _ => panic!(),
    }
    match a {
        Some(..) => println!("we are in match .."),
        _ => panic!(),
    }
```

Both do compile and run, but what is the reason to prefer one before another?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In this case, there is no difference.

In general, `_` ignores *one* element (field, array element, tuple field etc.) while `..` ignores everything left (all fields except those explicitly specified etc.). But since `Some` contains only one field, this has the same effect.

Here's an example where they differ:

```rust
struct Foo(u32, u32);

fn foo(v: Foo) {
    match v {
        Foo(..) => {}
        Foo(_, _) => {}
    }
}
```

Comment: One reason to prefer the `..` form (or even `Foo { .. }`, which also works even for tuple structs/enum variants) is because it makes the match robust to changes in the number of arguments or whether it uses the braced or tuple style in the declaration. (Or you can prefer the `_` form if you *want* the code to break and require review on any change to the variant.) When you have a whole bunch of variants with a variety of kinds of argument it is convenient to be able to write all the branches the same way.